# Getting CPU usage of a specific Service in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I want to know the CPU usage of a specific service in C#.

PerformanceCounter works fine with process:

```
PerformanceCounter counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", "myprocess", true);  
double result = counter.NextValue();
```

but not with services:

```
PerformanceCounter counter = new PerformanceCounter("Service", "% Processor Time", "myservice", true);  
double result = counter.NextValue();
```

Comment: Services are processes too

Comment: I've tried with "PerformanceCounter counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", "myservice", true);  
double result = counter.NextValue();" to get CPU usage of the Service but it don't works.

Comment: Stop using `myService` and use the real names, your changes is hiding the problem

Comment: I've tried with every services names which are running on my computer and it didn't works, ACDaemon for example.

Comment: I have the Exeption:"Instance ACDaemon does not exist in the specified Category"

Comment: If you check your list of Services and you go to properties for ACDaemon, what do you see in the "Path to Executable"? For example for "Apple Mobile Device Service" I see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W1dlT.png)

Comment: I see "ArcSoft Connect Daemon", it don't works with this too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89477/discussion-between-scott-chamberlain-and-userfloflo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct name for the performance counter would be

```
PerformanceCounter counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", "ACService", true);
```